# Root Account Compromised In Unknown Fashion

Tags: linux, security, ubuntu, ssh, redis

I have a server running Ubuntu 14.04-64 running OpenSSH 5.9 which started acting very strangely over the last few days.  SSH and HTTP connections were timing out.  In addition, my SSH key was no longer working.  I was having to use my password to login.  Then I got a notice from our hosting provider that the server had used up 400% of its allotted bandwidth for the month (5 days into the month) when we rarely go over 10%.  So I suspected the server had been compromised.

I saw no strange CPU activity in HTOP.  I saw no strange network activity in iftop.  However, there was a strange executable set up as a service in all of the rc.Xd directories:  S90.777{1452022308.  It called another executable in the / directory called .777{1452022308.  This process was running with a very high priority and thus was causing other connections to time out.  The file is a binary executable.

I examined the server logs and found this:

```
Jan  3 09:08:32 dev1 sshd[19757]: Accepted publickey for root from X.X.X.X port 41394 ssh2: RSA 31:1c:bd:a0:d0:56:1b:e0:fd:a3:05:cc:9e:96:4e:8c
```

We've never put public keys on any of our servers for root and never would.  The user was on the server for approximately 8 minutes and then disappeared.  The authorized_keys file in /root/.ssh is in binary format and unreadable.

I have no idea how a user would have been able to place an authorized keys file into /root.  This is incredible!

The other activity from the same IP address (in the auth log) is:

```
Jan  3 08:00:26 dev1 sshd[18907]: Connection closed by X.X.X.X [preauth]
Jan  3 08:31:01 dev1 sshd[19287]: Connection closed by X.X.X.X [preauth]
Jan  3 09:08:32 dev1 sshd[19757]: Accepted publickey for root from X.X.X.X port 41394 ssh2: RSA 31:1c:bd:a0:d0:56:1b:e0:fd:a3:05:cc:9e:96:4e:8c
Jan  3 09:16:26 dev1 sshd[19757]: Received disconnect from X.X.X.X: 11: disconnected by user
```

I've disabled root ssh logins on all of our other servers but I'm astonished at how this could have happened in the first place.  Does anyone have any idea how such a thing could have happened?

Comment: Running the `last` command should show you every logon event - does not tell you how and why, but may give you a clue as to who and when.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan - No, Softlayer.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what happened.  The most important piece of evidence was that the authorized_keys file in /root was in binary format.

I had recently installed redis on this server.  Apparently, if you don't bind redis to localhost, it can easily be manipulated into putting SSH keys into the authorized_keys file of the user that it is run under (in this case root).  In fact, the creator of redis describes this process in a blog post:  http://antirez.com/news/96

So, to summarize:

1. Bind redis to localhost or an internal network connection and keep it away from the internet.
2. Add an auth password to redis.
3. Run redis as its own user, not as root.